# Android compileSdk 33 targets SDK 24 in playstore

Tags: java, android, configuration, app-store, release

this is my defaultConfig

```html
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.portlmedia.streets"
        minSdkVersion 24
        compileSdk 33
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        buildConfigField "String", "WEBVIEW_URL", "\"https://streets.portlmedia.com\""
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
        }
    }
```

But when I created the .aab file and try to update to playstore, It shows me that the Target SDK is 24
[image]

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: You don't have a targetSDKVersion.  Add one.

Comment: I thought compileSdk  would do the magic

Comment: Nope.  They do different things.  TargetSDK specifies a set of behavior that you're targeting.  CompileSDK tells the compiler what version to use when compiling the app.  COmpileSDK I believe must be >= targetSDK, but you frequently use the most current version for compileSDK, regardless of target.  Compile SDK's biggest effect is that if you use compile 33, you can't use functionality added in 34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use:

```
        targetSdkVersion 33
```